# sound once lost doesn't come back

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-xp-sp3

Am developing a windows application that produces sound.
But sometimes the sound, once muted and unmuted, doesn't come back.
I raise the volume in the volume control but still nothing.

I read a solution about application related keys that are added in the registry at
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\Audio\PolicyConfig\PropertyStore
The solution consists of deleting the key related to the app if no sound available.
The sound comes back indeed but the problem I have is that it is recurrent. 
I mean, sometimes when the volume for that application is muted again, the sound disappears but can't bring it back when I unmute. It is not consistent, sometimes it happens but not always!

Question: 
Is there no way to prevent this from happening without having to delete the key every time the problem occurs?
Which (hidden)  Windows component makes the key to be added to the registry and the sound to be cut off?

thank you

Chris